# Query highest number of one-to-many relationships

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a "Like" system in place to track who likes what.

The `Like` model's `parent` is the object that is liked. This could be anything. For this example lets use a `Car`. The `Like` model also has an `account` property that determines who liked that `Car`.

I'm wondering if there's a way in datastore/NDB to query the highest number of likes. This isn't normalized to just have a raw number on the `Car` object, but I'm wondering if that's the only real way to do this.

Basically, if 10 different people like a single `Car` object, and 5 different people like a different `Car` object, what would be the query to list those to items out look like, with the count?

If I knew which `Car` objects to query for, I could simply query those on the `Like` table and just count the number of objects it has, and that obviously gives me the total `Like` count for that `Car`, but I'm going the other direction with it.

Comment: As I understand it, you could use an [ancestor query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#ancestor_queries). It limits its results to the specified entity and its descendants. Then you will only need to use SUM() or COUNT() to have the total amount of likes. If I missunderstood, it would be great if you could be more specific, or provide the schema you are explaining in the question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described it is not possible: without an actual counter property you'd first need to perform individual queries to get each of the relevant counts, then perform an additional step to determine the maximum of those counts.

If however you add a `liked` counter property to the liked objects (`Car` in your example), which you'd increment in the same transaction in which you create the corresponding `Like` entity, you will no longer need the first round of queries to get the counts. You will thus be able to perform a single query per kind of liked object (a query for `Car` entities in the example) - ordered (desc) by the `liked` property and maybe with a result count limit - which will give you the most liked object(s) of that kind.